# Minecraft causes Ubuntu 13.04 to freeze

Tags: 13.04, freeze, minecraft

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 and when I try to run Minecraft, after a few minutes the whole system freezes and I have to hold down the power button on my laptop and reboot as the laptop just completely stops responding.

I have tried with OpenJDK 6 & 7 and it crashes with both. I have tried removing mods, but it still happens. Is there any way that I can stop this from happening?

I am using the following graphics card:

> 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Sumo [Radeon HD 6380G]

I tried deleting the game data, and that did nothing. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> also did nothing after the crash, but for some reason my laptop refused to turn back on for a bit afterwards when I tried that command.

Comment: Post the output off `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: Could you please paste the results of `sudo lshw` in the Ubuntu Pastebin (http://paste.ubuntu.com/), and paste the resulting link here?

Comment: 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Sumo [Radeon HD 6380G]

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5746101/

Comment: Try deleting the game data in `./.mincraft/`

Comment: Also, what happens when you press (ctrl+alt+f1) after the crash?

Comment: I tried deleting the game data, and that did nothing. ctrl+alt+f1 also did nothing after the crash, but for some reason my laptop refused to turn back on for a bit afterwards when I tried that command

Answer (score 0):

You want to install proprietary graphics drivers if you haven't already. (You didn't mention that you did, so I'm just assuming you have not yet.) Open the Software Sources app, and click the "Additional Drivers" tab. You can install fglrx drivers from there, which will allow you to take full advantage of the card's capabilities and probably stop the crashes.

Comment: I have installed the proprietary graphics driver, and that has fixed the problem with the crashes, but I am now getting a little box on the bottom right of my screen which has the AMD logo at the top, and then says 'Unsupported Hardware' underneath. Is this going to be a problem or is it ok?

Comment: Ok, try selecting the fglrx-updates driver if it appears, instead, or install the fglrx-updates package.